# the Dragon Boat Festival, ON or AT?

Tags: prepositions

In an English textbook used in China, a sentence reads like this:

> We (Chinese) eat boat cakes **at** the Dragon Boat Festival.

FYI: the Dragon Boat Festival is a 1-day national holiday, which commemorates an ancient patriotic poet. In few southern areas in China, (official) festival activities, such as boat racing, are held on the day. However, eating the boat cake has spread across China even though the tradition has not been well observed because of the fast pace of life and the abundance of food choices.

In this case, which preposition should I use?

---

QUESTION EDITION

I will make my question really clear: in the following sentence, which preposition should I fill in the blank?

> We (Chinese) eat boat cakes **_____** the Dragon Boat Festival.

Please note:

1. The preposition to be filled in, though a 1-word prepotion is preferred, can be a phrase, e.g.: "**in front of**", but such phrases as "**on the day of...**" are **NOT** what I am looking for.
2. Again, there **IS** a set date for the 1-day festival in question, and there are almost **NO** activities held at home **NOR** events for anybody to go to, except that some Chinese eat the "boat cakes" (at home).
3. Please feel free to believe or confirm that "**the Dragon Boat Festival** in itself is a problematic term or translation", and hence the sentence is invalid and does not yield an answer.

Comment: Related question [Making out the difference between “at Christmas”, “in the Christmas holiday”, “on the Christmas day”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/148409/9161)

Comment: There is another option - you could eat boat cakes **during** the festival. If it is a traditional food that you might eat at home during the day of the festival (instead of going to the festival and buying cakes there), "during" might be a good choice. For example "Mooncake is the most popular and important food eaten during the Mid-Autumn Festival." ([source](https://www.chinahighlights.com/festivals/mid-autumn-festival-food.htm))

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you for your direction, but I'm sorry to say the link does NOT apply to my case. The Dragon Boat Festival is a set day and date without ambiguity, and the "during" solution does NOT really work with a 1-day national holiday. If you say ON and AT are both out (because DURING is idiomatic), I'm fine with that. My question is THIS: ON or AT. Any thoughts?

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your specific question - I put it there because it is related and might be of interest to other people who find this question.

Comment: It’s always on the 5th of lunar May. The date certainly changes from the perspective of solar calendar users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In British English, the preposition **at** is used for the following festivities:

1. **at Christmas**
   this holiday season includes Christmas Eve, Christmas Day, and St. Stephen's Day which is **on** 26 December (also called *Boxing Day*).
2. **at Easter**
   The Easter period includes Good Friday, Easter (which is always **on** a Sunday) and Easter Monday
3. **at New Year's**
   this refers to the period around New Year's Day. Some people begin celebrating early **on** New Year's Eve (in Scotland this day is known as *Hogmanay*) and some don't stop partying until late into the New Year.

Note that the preposition **on** refers to a specific date or day, thus we may say

> - What are you doing **on** New Year’s Day? (January 1)
>     *but*
> - What are you doing **at** New Year’s? (December 31 – January 1)
> - What are you doing **on** Christmas Day? (December 25)
>     *but*
> - What are you doing **at** Christmas? (December 24 – 26)

In the case of the Chinese holiday, **Dragon Boat Festival**, whose date is fixed *[on the 5th day of the 5th month of the traditional Chinese calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Boat_Festival)*, this means it changes every year. According to Wikipedia,    **in** 2017 the festival occurred **on** 30th May, but **in** 
2018 it fell **on** 18th June.

The date of Easter, on the Christian calendar, also changes every year. It occurs **on the first Sunday** after the first full moon that occurs **on** or **after** March 21. For example **in** 2017, Easter was **on** 16 April but this year it was **on** 1 April. Next year it will be **on** 21 April.

Therefore, in my experience, British English speakers will normally say

> - What are you doing **at** Easter?
>     *but*
> - What are you doing **on** Easter *Sunday*?

The  same “rules” could be applied to the Chinese festival

> - What are you doing **at** the Dragon Boat Festival? (around this period)
>     *but*
> - What are you doing **on** (the) Dragon Boat Festival?

Online, I found examples using *both* prepositions

### at

> 1. Visiting China at the Dragon Boat Festival…
> 2. The wine is drunk at the Dragon Boat Festival…
> 3. Make a splash at the Dragon Boat Festival
> 4. ABAX look forward to seeing the local people and businesses of Peterborough **at** the Dragon Boat Festival on Saturday 10th June 2017
> 5. What food do they eat **at** the Dragon Boat Festival?
> 6. It is a very popular practice to drink this kind of Chinese liquor seasoned with realgar **at** the Dragon Boat Festival
> 7. Casualties **at** the Dragon Boat Festival were common in China in the past as opponents could throw stones and sticks at participants.
> 8. Dragon Boat team members gather under the tent as they get ready to race **at** the Dragon Boat Festival Saturday morning, July 28, 2018 at...
> 9. Today, people still eat zongzi and participate in dragon boat races to commemorate Qu Yuan’s sacrifice **at** the Dragon Boat Festival (Duan Wu festival) on the fifth day of the fifth month of the Chinese lunar calendar.

### on (with and without the article *the*)

> 1. What activities do Chinese children do **on** Dragon Boat Festival?
> 2. Believe it or not, legend has it that at midday **on** Dragon Boat Festival day, you can balance an egg on its end.
> 3. What do people do **on** Dragon Boat Festival in different regions of China?
> 4. **On** Dragon Boat Festival, parents also need to dress their children up with a perfume pouch.
> 5. What do Chinese People Eat **on the** Dragon Boat Festival?
> 6. Zongzi or rice dumplings, is a traditional Chinese food always eaten **on the** Dragon Boat Festival on the fifth day of the fifth lunar month.
> 7. These [“Jung”, 五月粽 or Zong Zi] are often eaten at breakfast **on the** festival day which, as a day of rest, tends to start late so rice dumplings for brunch are quite common.
> 8. The custom of eating mianshanzi **on the** Dragon Boat Festival mainly prevails in Minqin County in Northwest China's Gansu Province.
> 9. Some areas will boil tea eggs and brine eggs to eat **on the** Dragon Boat Festival.
> 10. **On the** Dragon Boat Festival, children normally wear scented sachets to ward off evil. A scented sachet is an ornament worn on the front of the dress.

Comment: Thank you for your input, truly! What I’m going to say bears no intention of fault finding nor ungratefulness, but to discriminate the actual uses and give our discussion to a brighter prospect. I totally agree with your analysis on AT vs ON in general. As for your 9 examples of AT, to me, they're of 3 categories: unclear TIME or EVENT indication (example 1; 2 ), (more-)TIME-related uses (example 4; 5; 6; 9, which should be inappropriate preposition uses based on the definition of ON and AT), and (more-)EVENT-related uses (example 3; 7; 8).

Comment: Among the examples of ON, sentence 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 and 10 admittedly reflect the nature of the festival (1-day-long; with few public events available) and advocate the use of ON. Sentence 2 and 7, though seemingly support the use of ON, but they should be excluded as supporting evidence because there is no disagreement on the use of ON in front of “… DAY” structure.

Comment: Please approve my edition of your answer (to get the examples numbered) if it's up to you.

Comment: @S.Z.  ON: 2 and 7 remain, they specifically refer to the festival, 7. just omits the words "dragon boat". As for the example with AT yes, there is ambiguity between time (on a date) and event (at a feast), so it is open to interpretation.

Comment: Can I assume you are on board with me about ON but not AT?

Comment: I slipped and revised

Comment: @S.Z. I showed that either "at" and "on" can be used, and as evidence I provided real life examples. The examples also include what food and beverages are consumed on that day. I explained that either preposition can be used for the holiday "New Year's Day" which, objectively, is a single day but people begin celebrating the day/evening/night before. The example cited in your question is not wrong, and "on" could legitimately replace "at".

Comment: I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

Both uses of preposition are correct in your question. (If I'm interpreting your question correctly.)

> I eat boat cakes ***at*** **the Dragon Boat Festival**.
>   I eat boat cakes ***on*** **the day of** the Dragon Boat Festival.

In one sentence, the pronoun is followed by the festival itself. In the other sentence, the pronoun is followed by a time (the day).

---

To be more precise, it's the word used that determines the pronoun:

> I eat **at** the ***festival***.
>   I eat **on** the ***day***.

So, even though something may be the same thing, if different words are used, then a different preposition is used:

> I eat boat cakes **at** the Dragon Boat ***Festival***.
>   I eat boat cakes **on** Dragon Boat ***Day***.

(Assuming it had *Day* in its name.)

But if you aren't going **to** a local festival, then:

> I eat boat cakes **on** the ***day*** of the Dragon Boat Festival.

---

Similarly:

> I baked a cake **on** Christmas ***Day***.
>   I ate some cake **at** the Christmas ***party***.

But also:

> I took a cake **to** the Christmas ***party***.
>   I baked a cake **for** ***Christmas***.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83693/discussion-on-answer-by-jason-bassford-the-dragon-boat-festival-on-or-at).

Comment: @Jason Bassford please feel free to edit your answer now that I have made my question crystal clear. Thank you!